# Adjusting Polygon Visibility with CartoCSS

Tags: polygon, carto, zoom, cartocss, css

I am attempting to adjust the visibility of a polygon layer in Carto by zoom level.  To keep it simple for now I am looking to have the opacity of 1 from zoom 0-7 and opacity 0 from zoom 8+.  I am working directly in Carto (not tilemill, or elsewhere) and have tried a few methods.  Most notably, [this](https://carto.com/academy/courses/beginners-course/invisible-and-visible-data/) method (found on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155583/how-to-set-the-visibility-range-of-layers-on-cartodb-using-cartocss) question) only worked for point data, not polygons.

Getting the zooms to adjust for point data worked using the following, now I'm just trying to adapt it for use with polygons.

```
    #layer {
    marker-allow-overlap: true;
    [zoom = 0]{opacity:1}
    [zoom = 8]{opacity:0}
    }
```

Right now I've gotten myself stuck at

```
    #layer {
    [zoom = 0]{opacity:1}
    [zoom = 8]{opacity:0}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to [this guide](https://carto.com/academy/courses/beginners-course/invisible-and-visible-data/). Zooms need to be specified as ranges, you are changing opacity only for the zoom 0 and 8.

Example: go to http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/raw/d945737eb42ca83654301e66dac365cb/ and put this SQL to draw polygons

```
select * from world_borders
```

And this CartoCSS to render with different opacity based on zoom.

```
#layer{
  polygon-fill      : #fabada;
  line-color        : blue;
  line-opacity      : 0.5;
  line-width        : 3;

  [zoom>5]{
    line-color      : red;
    polygon-opacity : 0;
    line-opacity    : 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's one of the items I linked to in the question.  My issue is that it works on point data but not polygons and I cannot find in their documentation the necessary command for use with polygons.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Added example to my answer, polygon opacity is driven by the `polygon-opacity` property.